# htaccess deny subfolders from main domain but permit if linked by his own domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have more domains on the same server.
the file system is like this

/index.php
/page.php
/.....
/folder-for-domains/
/folder-for-domains/domain1.com-folder/
/folder-for-domains/domain2.com-folder/

domain.com is pointing to the / and the other domains are pointing to /folder-for-domains/domain1.com-folder/ or /folder-for-domains/domain2.com-folder/

I want to block the subdomain folders from the domain.com but permit these folders if linked with his own domain (domain1.com or domain2.com)

is it possible with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this but adding a `RewriteCond` statement checking the `Host` header value and then a `RewriteRule` to deny the access.

I think that it should also be possible to implement this by using `SetEnvIf` and then a `Deny from` statement